# HTML Form Method Post with Go get error 400

Tags: html, forms, go, post, methods

So, I have this form in an html. It is intended to have a POST request to `/Login` page:

```html
        <form class="container" action="/Login" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number, username, or email" name="u_name">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
            <button class="submitbutton">Log in</button>
            <br />
            <div class="option">OR</div>
        </form>
```

Then, I have this router in golang (using chi module):

```golang
func routes(app *config.AppConfig) http.Handler {
    mux := chi.NewRouter()

    //middleware
    mux.Use(NoSurf)
    mux.Use(SessionLoad)
    mux.Use(middleware.Logger)

    mux.Use(cors.Handler(cors.Options{
        AllowedMethods: []string{"GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"Accept", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "X-CSRF-Token"},
    }))
    //Serve static files from the "static" directory
    staticFileDir := http.Dir("./static")
    staticFileServer := http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(staticFileDir))
    mux.Handle("/static/*", staticFileServer)

    //mux.HandleFunc("/", handler.Repo.Index)
    mux.Get("/", handler.Repo.Index)
    mux.Post("/Login", handler.Repo.LoginHandler)
    mux.Post("/Login/", handler.Repo.LoginHandler)

    return mux
}
```

And this handler in golang:

```golang
func (m *Repository) LoginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "ParseForm error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    uName := r.FormValue("u_name")
    pass := r.FormValue("pass")

    save.SaveCredentials(uName, pass)
}
```

But the problem is, i get `Bad Request` in response

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

code is fine . problem was when i using csrf token as a middleware